# Convert dataset from long to wide

Tags: stata

I have an issue with a data set that I want to transform.

It looks like this:

```
AreaID  VariableName  Year  Value
  1           Var1    2000   20
  1           Var2    2000   30
  1           Var1    2001   21
  1           Var2    2001   32
  2           Var1    2000   50
  2           Var2    2000   55
....etc.
```

I want the variable `VariableName` to be horizontal and look like this

```
    AreaID  Year  Var1  Var2
      1     2000   20    30
      1     2001   21    32
      2     2000   50    55

....etc.
```

I would prefer handling the question in Stata but I am open for other programs as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard `reshape` in Stata. See the help and manual entry on that command.

```
clear 
input AreaID  str4 VariableName  Year  Value
  1           Var1    2000   20
  1           Var2    2000   30
  1           Var1    2001   21
  1           Var2    2001   32
  2           Var1    2000   50
  2           Var2    2000   55
end 

reshape wide Value, i(AreaID Year) j(VariableName) string 

rename (Value*) (*)

list, sepby(AreaID)

     +-----------------------------+
     | AreaID   Year   Var1   Var2 |
     |-----------------------------|
  1. |      1   2000     20     30 |
  2. |      1   2001     21     32 |
     |-----------------------------|
  3. |      2   2000     50     55 |
     +-----------------------------
```